# Function pointer with param of type using impl

Tags: rust

I am trying to correctly type a function pointer with the following signature:

```rust
pub fn do_thing_with_context(
    context: &mut impl IoContext,
) -> () {
    ...
}
```

My immediate thought was to type it in this way:

```rust
pub type MyFuncRef = fn(&mut impl IoContext) -> ();
```

However I've learned that `impl` isn't available while defining types.

The compiler recommended defining the type using `dyn` instead of `impl`, but this creates a new problem. I now get a compiler error when trying to pass a `do_thing_with_context` reference where a `MyFuncRef` is expected:

```
do_thing_with_context doesn't have a size known at compile-time
```

This makes sense to some extent; I understand why the size of `impl IoContext` would be unknown at compile time (since each implementor of the trait could be of a difference size).

What I don't understand yet is what options I have available to me to correctly type this and successfully pass around function references. Thanks for any insights.

Comment: Try: `type MyFuncRef<T: IoContext> = fn (&mut T) -> ()`

Comment: Or redefine `do_thing_with_context` to take a `&mut dyn IoContext` parameter.

Comment: Unrelated, but `fn() -> ()` can be typed as just `fn()`.

Comment: @Jmb `bounds on generic parameters are not enforced in type aliases` (compiler warning). The correct way is `type MyFuncRef<T> = fn(&mut T);`, then use it like `fn foo<T: IoContext>(f: MyFuncRef<T>)` (though I'm not sure what amount of advantage a type alias gives you here).

Comment: Ahh yeah, thanks @ChayimFriedman. The real function returned a value, just wrote the above for MRE purposes. Good to know though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work, using either a type with a trait, or by an unstable feature trait_alias?

```rust
#![feature(trait_alias)]
pub trait IoContext {}

struct MyContext {}
impl IoContext for MyContext {}

pub fn do_thing_with_context(
    context: &mut impl IoContext,
) -> () {
    ()
}

pub trait MyFuncRefTraitAlias<IO> = Fn(&mut IO) ;

fn use_fn_ref_trait_alias<F: MyFuncRefTraitAlias<IO>, IO: IoContext>(context: &mut IO, f: F) {
    f(context)
}

pub type MyFuncRefTyped<IO> = fn(&mut IO);

fn use_fn_ref_typed<IO: IoContext>(context: &mut IO, f: MyFuncRefTyped<IO>) {
    f(context)
}

fn main() {
    let mut context = MyContext {};
    let fn_ref = do_thing_with_context;
    use_fn_ref_trait_alias(&mut context, fn_ref);
    use_fn_ref_typed(&mut context, fn_ref);
}
```

Note that you can not use type alias bounds in this case for `IO` or `F` (e.g. `type MyFuncRef<IO: IoContext, F>`), see https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/nightly-rustc/rustc_lint/builtin/static.TYPE_ALIAS_BOUNDS.html